# Recursive Runtime - Space Complexity (pg.44 of Cracking the Coding Interview)

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

On pg. 44 of Cracking the Coding Interview, there is the following algo:

```
int f(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return f(n - 1) + f(n - 1);
}
```

The book says that this has time complexity of O(2^n) and space-complexity of O(n). I get the time complexity part since there are O(2^n) nodes created. I don't understand why the space-complexity is not also that. The book says because it's because only O(n) nodes exist at any given time.

How can that be? Wouldn't the call-stack have all 2^n calls when we are at the bottom level of f(1)? What am I missing?

Please let me know if I can provide more detail.

Thanks,

Comment: No, the call stack only reaches a level of `n` calls before recursion stops.  At each depth, `n` is one less, so none of the recursive calls can affect the maximum call depth.

Comment: The second call to `f(n-1)` doesn't take place until after the first one returns.  They do not occupy stack space at the same time.  And the same at every other level.

Comment: Thank you both! That was helpful, particularly @Nate Eldredge. If you want to designate as the answer, I will accept it!

Comment: I am not convinced by the answer. I posit that @NateEldredge's explanation, "The second call to f(n-1) doesn't take place until after the first one returns" is making an assumption about that way a call stack operates. A naive implementation of a call stack may not follow this assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The second call to `f(n-1)` doesn't take place until after the first one returns, so they do not occupy stack space at the same time. When the first one returns, its stack space is freed and may be reused for the second call.

The same applies at every level of the recursion.  The memory used is proportional to the maximum *depth* of the call tree, not the overall number of nodes.